# Extend a class in Python which is later created

Tags: python

I know that it usually recommended to extend classes like this example where the `Volvo` class is extends the class `Car`:

```
import Car
class Volvo(Car):
    do stuff...
```

In my situation I would like to define the class `Volvo` before I create the instance of `Car`. So I would like to do something like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed_limit):
        self.speed_limit = speed_limit
    
    def print_current_speed_limit(self):
        print(self.speed_limit)

class Volvo(Car):
    def __init__(self, car, modified_speed_limit):
        self = car
        self.speed_limit += modified_speed_limit
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    car = Car(130)
    volvo = Volvo(car, 20)
    volvo.print_current_speed_limit()
```

However this fails and prints that volvo does not have a `print_current_speed_limit` function (which is correct). When I run the example in the debugger I see that after `self` is replaced with `car` it has the `print_current_speed_limit` function however not afterwards on the last line of the example.

The code that I'm working with is much more complicated but I tried to make a smaller example here. It is not one simple variable (like `speed_limit` and the function `print_current_speed_limit`) in my real example that I would like to use from `Car` in `Volvo`.

Maybe I'm just trying to find a solution that does not exist and that I should update my code so I can use the "correct way" of extending classes..

Comment: `volvo` instance here has `print_current-speed_limit` method but it doesn't have `.speed_limit` attribute because parent class `Car`'s constructor wasn't called yet

Comment: That's not how inheritance works at all. You don't need to instantiate `Car` before you instantiate `Volvo`. `self = car` does nothing, or at least not what you think it does.

Comment: BTW, `volvo` *does* have a `print_current_speed_limit` method. But when calling that method, `volvo`/`self` does not have a `speed_limit` attribute, because it never got assigned. It's `print(self.speed_limit)` that's failing, not `volvo.print_current_speed_limit()`.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed_limit):
        self.speed_limit = speed_limit
    
    def print_current_speed_limit(self):
        print(self.speed_limit)

class Volvo(Car):
    def __init__(self, c, modified_speed_limit):
        super(Volvo, self).__init__((c.speed_limit+modified_speed_limit))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    car = Car(130)
    volvo = Volvo(car,20)
    volvo.print_current_speed_limit()   #150
```

another version:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed_limit):
        self.speed_limit = speed_limit
    
    def print_current_speed_limit(self):
        print(self.speed_limit)

class Volvo(Car):
    def __init__(self, modified_speed_limit):
        super(Volvo, self).__init__(modified_speed_limit)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    car = Car(130)
    volvo = Volvo(car.speed_limit+20)
    volvo.print_current_speed_limit()   #150
```

Comment: Almost, in that example I hoped to get `150` as output

Comment: I've changed my answer